# Using the RDP control to login to a Vista machine that requires Network Level Authentication

Tags: com, activex, rdp, nla

I'm trying to use the mstscax.dll (Microsoft Remote Desktop Control) to login to a Vista machine that requires Network Level Authentication.

I've played around with all the methods in IMsRdpClientNonScriptable4, IMsRdpClientAdvancedSettings4 and IMsRdpClient6. There are a slew of functions that appear that the might enable this.

- EnableCredSspSupport
- PromptForCredentials
- PromptForCredsOnClient
- NegotiateSecurityLayer

Unfortunately the MSDN documentation is pratacily useless and I can find no examples for any of these on the web. I know that it's possible because a product called "Royal TS" can connect this way.

One hint is that both "Royal TS" and Vista's Remote Desktop create a authoriztion prompt that looks like the one from CredUIPromptForWindowsCredentials, this makes me belive that i might be able to use a function like that to get the credential and then possibly use PublisherCertificateChain to tell RDP about it.

Any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if other people find this:

All that needs to be done is EnableCredSspSupport=true, the problem I had was that I was loading the mstscax.dll manually and the version I was using supported the IMsRdpClientNonScriptable4 interface but simply didn't work. If you just load the control normally just setting EnableCredSspSupport=true works fine.

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking at this for about an hour and this saved me probabbly another couple of hours.

Answer (score 1):

This property maybe help you

**RDPControl.AdvancedSettings8.EnableCredSspSupport = true;**

In addition, It also depend on your OS support Network Level Authentication or not.

Reference (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff393716(v=ws.10).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried to do what you're doing but I suggest you take a look at the following article:

[Multi Remote Desktop Client .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/RemoteDesktopClient.aspx)

The projects uses mstscax.dll.