# terraform windows server 2016 in Azure and domain join issue logging in to domain with network level authentication error message

Tags: windows, azure, terraform

I successfully got a windows server 2016 to come up and join the domain.  However, when I go to remote desktop login it throws an error about network level authentication.  Something about domain controller cannot be contacted to perform Network Level Authentication (NLA).

I saw some video on work arounds at https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=requires+network+level+authentication+error&docid=608000415751557665&mid=8CE580438CBAEAC747AC8CE580438CBAEAC747AC&view=detail&FORM=VIRE.

Is there a way to address this with terraform and up front instead?

To join domain I am using:

```
    name = "domjoin"
    virtual_machine_id = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm_windows_vm.id
    publisher = "Microsoft.Compute"
    type = "JsonADDomainExtension"
    type_handler_version = "1.3"
    settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
    "Name": "mydomain.com",
    "User": "mydomain.com\\myuser",
    "Restart": "true",
    "Options": "3"
    }
    SETTINGS

    protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
    {
    "Password": "${var.admin_password}"
    }
    PROTECTED_SETTINGS
    depends_on = [ azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm_windows_vm ]
```

Is there an option I should add in this domjoin code perhaps?

I can log in with my local admin account just fine.  I see the server is connected to the domain.  A nslookup on the domain shows an ip address that was configured to be reachable by firewall rules, so it can reach the domain controller.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there might be some settings that could help out, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948660/using-the-rdp-control-to-login-to-a-vista-machine-that-requires-network-level-au), possibly all that is needed might be:
`"EnableCredSspSupport": "true"` inside your domjoin settings block.

You might also need to do something with the registry on the server side, which can be done by using `remote-exec`.

For example something like:

```
resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "example" {
  name                  = "example-vm"
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.example.id]
  vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2019-Datacenter"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "example-os-disk"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "example-vm"
    admin_username = "adminuser"
    admin_password = "SuperSecurePassword1234!"
  }

  os_profile_windows_config {
    provision_vm_agent = true
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "echo Updating Windows...",
      "powershell.exe -Command \"& {Get-WindowsUpdate -Install}\"",
      "echo Done updating Windows."
    ]

    connection {
      type        = "winrm"
      user        = "adminuser"
      password    = "SuperSecurePassword1234!"
      timeout     = "30m"
    }
  }
}
```

In order to set the correct keys in the registry you might need something like this inside the `remote-exec` block (I have not validated this code) :

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\Winstations\RDP-tcp' -Name 'SecurityLayer' -Value 0
```

In order to make the Terraform config cleaner I would recommend using templates for the Powershell script, see [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/templatefile)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, that was a brilliant response.  I will try it out.

Comment: Good to hear, let me know if it works